# Downloading website html content using WebClient issues a 407 response, why?

Tags: .net, webclient

```
public const string url = 
"http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/prices-and-markets/international-markets/indices/home/ftse-mib.html";

public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    string s = wc.DownloadString(url);
}
```

When I run this code I get the error message: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required. I have no idea what to do, can someone give me some advice?

Comment: Hi there! You don't seem to have accepted any answers to your questions. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/faq on how and why to do that. If you're not getting any satisfactory answers, try asking simpler, more to the point questions.

Comment: And to give a speculative answer - you probably get that error because the LSE wants to prevent crawlers from harvesting their data without paying for a license to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Testing...");

WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy(url); 
proxyObject.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
wc.Proxy = proxyObject;

string s = wc.DownloadString(url);
```

Refer [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx) to know about WebClient Headers.

Comment: Hi Knvn, I get unable to connect to the remote server when I try this code

Comment: are you getting this on WebProxy? what is the inner exception?